# Failling to build a Django project in VS 2015 - django\contrib\admin\widgets.py

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2015

I'm having a hard time building my Django project in VS 2015. Background: I have this project up and running on Eclipse so far, but I would like to import it to VS 2015 (Professional). I've download and installed VS IDE and Python Tools for VS 2.2.6.

--

First, I have had a Build FAILED error with no error messages. After some googling, I've changed the options from Build output messages from *Minimal* to *Diagnostic*, and found out that the problem seemed to be with my `PYTHONPATH`.

Then, I've added a `Search Path` to my python34 site-packages folder (again, after some research, I believe this is the right path).

After doing so, the build now fails again, but there are several "**unexpected token**" errors in the same file, localed in django/contrib/admin/**widgets.py**.

I've compared my file with the file in the official github page of django, and both files have some differences. Running the get version from the interactive window, I can see that my Django version is 1.11.6.

Is overwritting this file for the one in the github a good solution? Perhaps the installation have gone wrong at some point? What should I do?

-- EDIT --

Overwritting the file did not resolve it, as the same block of code appears in both files. It seems to be related with:

```
if params:
    related_url += '?' + '&amp;'.join(
        '%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in params.items(),
    )
    context['related_url'] = mark_safe(related_url)
    context['link_title'] = _('Lookup')
```

Errors are:

*Error  unexpected token ','    C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py*

*Error  unexpected token ')'    C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py*

*Error  unexpected token 'dedent'   C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py*

*Error  unexpected token 'newline'  C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py*

And the last one related to the eof

*Error  unexpected end of file  C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py*

--EDIT 2--

I've made a test by creating a new project and build + run it, and it succeeds. As I'm new to Django, I'm not sure if the reason why it succeeds is that this new project is not reaching this **widgets.py** file.

Comment: Try running `pip install django==1.11.6 --upgrade --force` and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Woah, Successfully installed django-1.11.6 pytz-2017.2, and it seems to be working fine now. Could you make that an answer (and elaborate the why that resolve the issue, if possible) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think somehow your Django package has got corrupted and altered. You shouldn't repair these things by manually copying files, rather you should re-install the package

Try running

```
pip install django==1.11.6 --upgrade --force
```

`--upgrade` and `--force` will make sure the django and its dependencies are reinstalled